# Symfony does not open a page

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony5.4

I have a page (archives) that works locally. But not on the server. In the logs I get the following message:

```
        AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: [info] Matched route "app_archive".
    PHP message: [debug] Read existing security token from the session.
    PHP message: [debug] SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.roles AS roles_2, t0.password AS password_3, t0.email AS email_4, t0.firstname AS firstname_5, t0.lastname AS lastname_6, t0.token AS token_7, t0.is_active AS is_active_8, t0.is_token_used AS is_token_used_9 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
    PHP message: [debug] User was reloaded from a user provider.
    PHP message: [debug] Notified event "debug.security.authorization.vote" to listener "Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\EventListener\\VoteListener::onVoterVote".

PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleListener::setDefaultLocale".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleAwareListener::onKernelRequest".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\Debug\\TraceableFirewallListener::configureLogoutUrlGenerator".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\Debug\\TraceableFirewallListener::onKernelRequest".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\DataCollector\\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DataCollector\\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.controller_arguments" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ErrorListener::onControllerArguments".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "debug.security.authorization.vote" to listener "Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\EventListener\\VoteListener::onVoterVote".
PHP message: [debug] SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.roles AS roles_2, t0.password AS password_3, t0.email AS email_4, t0.firstname AS firstname_5, t0.lastname AS lastname_6, t0.token AS token_7, t0.is_active AS is_active_8, t0.is_token_used AS is_token_used_9 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
PHP message: [debug] SELECT p0_.id AS id_0, p0_.date AS date_1, p0_.start_time AS start_time_2, p0_.end_time AS end_time_3, p0_.reason AS reason_4, p0_.minutes AS minutes_5, p0_.has_bonus AS has_bonus_6, p0_.is_archived AS is_archived_7, p0_.is_locked AS is_locked_8, p0_.is_deleted AS is_deleted_9, p0_.has_manual_minutes AS has_manual_minutes_10, p0_.user_id AS user_id_11 FROM positive_time p1_, positive_time p0_ WHERE p0_.is_archived = '1' AND p0_.user_id = ? ORDER BY p0_.date ASC
PHP message: [debug] SELECT n0_.id AS id_0, n0_.date AS date_1, n0_.start_time AS start_time_2, n0_.end_time AS end_time_3, n0_.reason AS reason_4, n0_.minutes AS minutes_5, n0_.is_archived AS is_archived_6, n0_.is_locked AS is_locked_7, n0_.is_deleted AS is_deleted_8, n0_.user_id AS user_id_9 FROM negative_time n1_, negative_time n0_ WHERE n0_.user_id = ? AND n0_.is_archived = '1' ORDER BY n0_.date ASC
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "debug.security.authorization.vote" to listener "Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\EventListener\\VoteListener::onVoterVote".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "debug.security.authorization.vote" to listener "Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\EventListener\\VoteListener::onVoterVote".
PHP message: [debug] Stored the security token in the session.
PHP message: [debug] SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DataCollector\\RequestDataCollector::onKernelResponse".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\RememberMe\\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ErrorListener::removeCspHeader".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\\Bundle\\WebProfilerBundle\\EventListener\\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\DisallowRobotsIndexingListener::onResponse".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\SessionListener::onKernelResponse".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\SessionListener::onFinishRequest".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\Debug\\TraceableFirewallListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleAwareListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
', referer: ....
```

EDIT: I formatted my code. That was only one line.
If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Please format the log output! Unreadable as one-liner.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.